# Зашифровать массив байт

Tags: c#, шифрование

Пишу чат. Хочу зашифровать сообщения по алгоритму [Диффи Хеллмана](https://habrahabr.ru/post/151599/). Предположим, алгоритм реализован и вот у нас есть заветный ключ. Какие есть алгоритмы, чтобы с помощью этого ключа зашифровать массив байт (сообщение)?

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;


class Alice
{
    public static byte[] alicePublicKey;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ECDiffieHellmanCng alice = new ECDiffieHellmanCng())
        {

            alice.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
            alice.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
            alicePublicKey = alice.PublicKey.ToByteArray();

            Bob bob = new Bob();
            CngKey k = CngKey.Import(bob.bobPublicKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
            byte[] aliceKey = alice.DeriveKeyMaterial(k);
            byte[] encryptedMessage = null;
            byte[] iv = null;
            Send(aliceKey, "Secret message", out encryptedMessage, out iv);
            bob.Receive(encryptedMessage, iv);
        }

    }

    private static void Send(byte[] key, string secretMessage, out byte[] encryptedMessage, out byte[] iv)
    {
        using (Aes aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aes.Key = key;
            iv = aes.IV;

            // Encrypt the message
            using (MemoryStream ciphertext = new MemoryStream())
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ciphertext, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                byte[] plaintextMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretMessage);
                cs.Write(plaintextMessage, 0, plaintextMessage.Length);
                cs.Close();
                encryptedMessage = ciphertext.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

}





public class Bob 
{
    public byte[] bobPublicKey;
    private byte[] bobKey;
    public Bob()
    {
        using (ECDiffieHellmanCng bob = new ECDiffieHellmanCng())
        {

            bob.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
            bob.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
            bobPublicKey = bob.PublicKey.ToByteArray();
            bobKey = bob.DeriveKeyMaterial(CngKey.Import(Alice.alicePublicKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob));

        }
    }

    public void Receive(byte[] encryptedMessage, byte[] iv)
    {

        using (Aes aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aes.Key = bobKey;
            aes.IV = iv;
            // Decrypt the message
            using (MemoryStream plaintext = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(plaintext, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(encryptedMessage, 0, encryptedMessage.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                    string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plaintext.ToArray());
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Зачем нужен массив iv?

Comment: >алгоритм реализован. Это как? сами делали или брали вот тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Благодарю, не знал что для этого в c# уже есть классы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь два вопроса:

> Какие есть алгоритмы, чтобы с помощью этого ключа зашифровать массив байт (сообщение)?

Подойдет любой симметричный алгоритм, [см., например, список тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B#.D0.92.D0.B8.D0.B4.D1.8B_.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85_.D1.88.D0.B8.D1.84.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2). Вот для чего может применяться связка симметричного и асимметричного шифрования:

1. Клиент хранит у себя публичный ключ асиметричного шифрования
2. Клиент придумывает новый пароль для симметричного шифрования
3. Клиент составляет сообщение для сервера, где будут пароль, дата и соль
4. Клиент шифрует пакет с помощью публичного ключа и отсылает на сервер
5. Сервер проверяет, что сообщение более-менее новое, соль корректна и т.д., запоминает пароль для симметричного шифрования, создает ответное сообщение, что всё ок.
6. Сервер шифрует это сообщение с помощью симметричного алгоритма и отправляет клиенту

Всё, теперь соединение установлено с помощью пароля клиента, сервер подтвердил, что он есть он (ибо знал приватный ключ на шаге 5). По пути еще есть тонкости того, какую соль выбрать и т.д.

> Зачем нужен массив iv?

Для усиление шифрования. Дело в том, что если в сообщении много повторяющихся символов, соотношение 0 к 1 не 50/50, а иное и т.д., то зная это, можно в отдельных случаях упростить взлом. Также проблема возникает, если блочным шифром работать с невыравненным сообщением, ну то есть если размер блока 64, а сообщение будет 65 (то есть последний блок будет почти весь состоять из нулей). Аналогично, два одинаковых блока сообщения будут иметь одинаковые зашифрованные пакеты [(см. тут)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.iv(v=vs.100).aspx)
Для этого применяется псевдорандомная последовательность, которая помогает убрать корреляции из исходного текста, выравняв соотношение 0 и 1, убрав повторы и т.д. 
Простой рандом тут будет неправильный, используют хитрые последовательности, в каждом элементе которых есть примерно одинаковое число нулей и единиц.

Comment: Является ли вектор секретным параметром? Зная его можно декодировать сообщение?

Comment: Нет, не является. Я бы советовал использовать класс RNGCryptoServiceProvider (конструктор без параметров) - он уже даст необходимую защиту.

Comment: Зачем обманывать? Вектор инициализации не имеет ни малейшего отношения к выравниванию или рандомизации.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы с помощью сессионного ключа зашифровать сообщение, можно использовать любой алгоритм симметричного шифрования.

Самыми популярными являются, наверное, вот эти:

- RC4
- 3DES
- AES
- "Кузнечик" (он же "ГОСТ")

Первые два довольно простые для самостоятельной реализации - но они уже устарели.

Comment: Расскажите, пожалуйста, зачем нужен вектор инициализации в AES? И должен ли он быть одинаковым при шифрации и дешифрации?

Comment: @SanychGoilo слишком много буков для комментария

Comment: так напишите ответ.

Comment: @SanychGoilo так задайте новый вопрос